# Fit a double exponential curve in R

Tags: r, exponential

I have a set of data which looks like this:

```
Time    Al Biochar  Al FeO  Cu Biochar  Cu FeO
 0      0.218223461 0.218223461      12.39823125     12.39823125
0.5    0.1395087   0.041177135      0.00543732      3.759749493
1      0.08415793  -0.134641447    -12.38861634    -4.177991174
1.5   -0.005332069 -0.316522561    -24.78366292    -12.52075324
2     -0.060324192 -0.500248756    -37.17868817    -20.59065175
2.5    -0.087457366 -0.635370352    -49.57529656    -28.45255875
3      -0.128805357 -0.800601678    -61.9718953 -37.06576867
4   -0.189998798    -0.900340101    -74.36721169    -45.37149157
5   -0.264429401    -1.015069379    -86.76336658    -56.68657815
6.5 -0.303092011    -1.111173198    -99.15624929    -67.18844927
```

And I'd like to fit the following double exponential decay equation to my line

> y = a * exp(-bx) +c * exp(-dx)

I'm fine with the graphing etc, just would like to know how to fit the exponential decay to give a line of best fit and give the r2 value for that fit as well as the values for a,b,c and d.

Also how do I plot that fit afterwards?

I'd like to know how to do this in R preferably.

I have the following code which isn't working correctly

```
mydata <- read.csv("B5cumul.csv")
fitData <- data.frame(mydata$Time, mydata$Al.Biochar)
plot(mydata$Time, mydata$Al.Biochar, type="b", 
     xlab="Time (hour)", ylab="Al removal (mg/L)")
# a is plateau. b is the amplitude of fast phase, r1 is the fast constant. 
# (y[1]-a-b) is the amplitude of slow phase, r2 is the slow constant.
f = function (a, r1, r2, b) {
  a + (b * exp(-(r1 * mydata$Time))) + ((mydata$Al.Biochar -a-b) * exp(-(r2 * x)))
}
  fit <- nls(f, data=fitData, start=list(a=0.25, r1=0.05, r2=1e-5, b=0.22), 
       algorithm="port")
```

And I'm not sure which values to use for a, b c and d.  I get the error 
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure a double exponential function makes sense? Because that's not what the data supports.

```
df <- read.table(
    text = "Time    'Al Biochar'  'Al FeO'  'Cu Biochar'  'Cu FeO'
 0      0.218223461 0.218223461      12.39823125     12.39823125
0.5    0.1395087   0.041177135      0.00543732      3.759749493
1      0.08415793  -0.134641447    -12.38861634    -4.177991174
1.5   -0.005332069 -0.316522561    -24.78366292    -12.52075324
2     -0.060324192 -0.500248756    -37.17868817    -20.59065175
2.5    -0.087457366 -0.635370352    -49.57529656    -28.45255875
3      -0.128805357 -0.800601678    -61.9718953 -37.06576867
4   -0.189998798    -0.900340101    -74.36721169    -45.37149157
5   -0.264429401    -1.015069379    -86.76336658    -56.68657815
6.5 -0.303092011    -1.111173198    -99.15624929    -67.18844927", header = T)


df %>%
    gather(what, value, 2:5) %>%
    mutate(unit = ifelse(grepl("Cu", what), "ug/L", "mg/L")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Time, value, colour = what)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        facet_wrap(~ unit, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Also relevant: [Double exponential fit in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261673/double-exponential-fit-in-r)

Comment: The Cu data is in micrograms/L and the Al data is in mg/L they should be on separate y axes. If you look at the Cu data on this curve you can see there is a fast phase and a slower phase on the graph. Can you think of a better way of fitting a model in R? It is more of a two phase linear curve really.

Comment: @LucyHaleEvans I updated the plot; but I don't see a fast and slow phase in any of the plots. I would start with a normal exponential. Instead of using `nls` (which can be very sensitive to starting values), I'd do a log-transformation of the data and use a linear model. Then assess the quality of the fit, and take it from there.

Comment: @LucyHaleEvans Also: If the units are ug/L and mg/L, why are the values negative?

Comment: @LucyHaleEvans And lastly: "Double exponential" is somewhat misleading. You want to fit the linear combination of two exponential functions; [this is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function) what's more commonly understood under a double exponential function. Admittedly, the CrossValidated link is closer to your definition.

Comment: Its double exponential decay that I was looking to fit (hence negative removal , its cumulatvie removal of Al by a treatment ). Apologies for not explaining that earlier. @MauritsEvers

Comment: The first part of the Cu line is steeper (hence faster) removal of Cu than the second part ( time hour 3 onwards. )

Comment: @LucyHaleEvans I still don't understand why values are negative. I can guarantee you that any fit estimates assuming a double exponential decay (if you manage to get them at all) will be close to statistically meaningless; i.e. their associated confidence intervals will be very large.   I guess 10 measurements and 4 model parameters don't work well together to characterise such a small effect. Personally, I don't really see that effect you describe at all.

Comment: I've had a go in sigma plot and the r2 value is pretty high(0.95-0.99). I will now evaluate the parameters, to asses the model fit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sigma plot. But a large R^2 value doesn't surprise. With 4 parameters and 10 measurements you're in overfitting territory; I would say that that's supported by the R^2 value being so close to 1. It would be interesting (and not difficult) to fit the data with a Bayesian `rstan`/`Stan` model. If I get a chance, I'll play around with this in the next days; I'm still unsure about some aspects of your data. Can you clarify why values are negative?